# combining arrays to get 3rd array value

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing a profile quiz.  This is just an example of code.  Ultimately I will do a loop for all possible combinations.  Basically, if the student chooses answer 3 to question 1 (what is your height - small, medium, large, xl, xxl) I want their pgheight to be stored as 4, sgheight as 9, cheight as 4, etc... My final array will consist of 16 $pos and 16 $attr with 5 scores for each combination.  Hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help.
e.g.

```
function height(){
    $pos=array("pg","sg","c");
    $attr=array("height","weight","strength");
    $pgheight=array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $sgheight=array(6,7,8,9,10);
    $cheight=array(1,2,3,4,5);

    $ans=3;
    $i=0;

    // THIS IS THE CODE THAT DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK.
    // My logic is $pgheight=$pgheight[3];  
    $pos[$i].$attr[$i]=$pos[$i].$attr[$i]."[".$ans."]"; 
    echo $pgheight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either want to eval the statement or use two dollar signs.  you're reusing the variable pgheight so its a bit confusing. let me give you an example instead.

```
$fruit = array("apples", "oranges", "pears");
$drinks = array("beer", "cider", "wine");

$krislikes = "drinks";
$whichone = 0;

echo "Kris likes " . ${$krislikes}[$whichone] . "<br>";
// or 
$answer = $$krislikes;
echo "Kris likes " . $answer[$whichone] . "<br>";
// or 
eval('$the_answer=$' . $krislikes . '[' . $whichone . '];');
echo "Kris likes " . $the_answer . "<br>";
```

hope that helps.